# JSON Glossary filter - possible to skip over some div elements on the page?

Tags: jquery, json

I am new to JSON, but am using a basic terms.json file as a glossary filter. The jQuery code on the page that pulls in the glossary file is incredibly simple:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('body').glossary('terms.json', {
            showonce: true
        });
    });

</script>
```

The issue is that I only want it to provide the rollover glossary for items within a specific div, not everywhere. I thought all I'd have to do is change 'body' to that specific div element, but that doesn't seem to be working... is this possible to do and, if so, how?

Comment: are you using selector for div with hash followed by div id `jQuery('#divid')` ?

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I did not realize I had to use the # symbol in front of the div name.

Comment: `#foo` matches dom ID "foo", `.foo` matches classname "foo".

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, the 'body' can be changed to a '#divid' and it will work.